# 13.04 Upgrade with NVidia

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, xorg, 13.04

Ubuntu 13.04 upgraded from 12.10
3.8.0-10-generic
Nvidia GeForce 310 r a2 (GT218) Graphics Card
Samsung 1920x1200 display

I received the notice to update to 13.04 the other day and I accepted it - that was a mistake. Now 3 days later I still don't have X back alive. The upgrade did not reboot with Nvidia working. I have tried all types of things including downloading the 313.30 driver and installing it.

After that I can boot to the X login - and log in - but the display is trying to run at 640x480 and there is no way to get to a terminal (or anything) - I just see the background. I can get to a terminal via ctrl-alt-f1 and log. However, I can't figure out how to get a proper Xconfig file structured to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: run sudo nvidia-xconfig

Answer (score 1):

You are a little troubled there.
I stumbled on similar issues yesterday while trying to build a system with xubuntu 13.04, on a old box. It seams that the nvidia drivers dont get along with latest kernel and/or X.org. I'm even unable to install the proprietary drivers from nvidia page (it seams to look for the sources in the wrong place, or expect an outdated files structure).

I have this one, with a GeForce4 MX 4000 working with nouveau driver, that is what installs by default. i decided to go on like this after several attempts to get some specific additional drivers working (and failing miserably). It mess up boot animation, and text console get weirdly small (it only uses like 2/3 of the actual screen), and give many glitches, but its kind of usable for me, as long as i will mainly access it remotely.

I still hope that nvidia or the people of canonical shows up with a 13.04 nvidia-96 latest-version-of-kernel-and-X compatible driver (not sure if you need those, or another, less ancient).

In order to regain access to your system, y would go apt-get remove --purge nvidia* , and try to install nouveau. I bet it will give you *some* desktop at least. Many users are having similar issues. You can find a lot of other suggestions out there.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

These steps may be generic enough to solve your problem.

First, on a fresh install, don’t login to the graphic interface, but press **Ctrl-Alt-F1** at the login prompt to get a text console login. Now issue the following commands:

```
sudo su

apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-generic
apt-get dist-upgrade

reboot
```

After reboot, log in again (Ctrl-Alt-F1 to do so in text mode). Become root again.

```
sudo su

apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

After this has been installed, you will get a number of status messages saying you’re done and that the drivers are installed. You are not done. If you reboot now, your computer will boot back to a black screen and be effectively bricked.

```
nvidia-xconfig
reboot
```

Sauce:

http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/